# random_state on train_test_split() appears to have large effect in performance metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

To summarize the problem: I have a data set with ~1450 samples, 19 features and a binary outcome where classes are fairly balanced (0.51 to 0.49).

I split the data into a train set and a test set using train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 42).

I am using the train set to tune hyper-parameters in algorithms optimizing for specificity, using GridSearchCV, with a RepeatedStratifiedKFold (10 splits, 3 repeats) cross-validation, and scoring=make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=0). I am then using the predictions on the test set to evaluate several metrics including specificity.

I started with a linear SVM (adjusting C), just to test out the process, and to my surprise the, grid_search.best_score_ is ~0.67, but while evaluating the test set it was ~0.55, it seemed like a large difference to me and I was unsure what was happening. I did a lot of troubleshooting to try and eliminate any PEBMAC, and as a last resort I decided to take the same code and just loop through random_state/seed in train_test_split(), and I calculated the difference between .best_score_ and the test score, turns out:

[image: plot with difference between best specificity and test specificity varying with random_state]

It appears that by using random_state=42, I unknowingly chose the random state (between 0 and 99) with the largest difference between the grid search best score, and the specificity in test set predictions.

While this difference worries me, what worries me more is that a lot seems to vary with the random state, including the best value of C, (and other metrics such as accuracy (10% variation between min and max), precision (14% variation between min and max), recall (17% variation between min and max), ...), making me doubt how to actually evaluate and report the best hyperparameters, as well as metrics for this model, since the choice of how it is split seems to have such a major influence.

Is there a better way to get actually representative metrics of the model? (that don't greatly vary with the way it is split?). Is my method just flawed, and there is a gold standard to this that I am missing?

Sorry for the wall of text!

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Considering [Erwan](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/64377/erwan)'s comment that optimizing for specificity might be contributing to the problem (and it still might), I ran the same experiment optimizing for accuracy, striking differences are still apparent: [image: plot with difference between best accuracy and test accuracy varying with random_state]

Coincidentally 42 still seems to be a fairly "unlucky" random state in terms of the difference between best accuracy score and test accuracy score.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It seems strange to me to optimize and evaluate on specificity alone: there's a risk that the model would predict a large majority of positives in order to avoid false negative errors. This might contribute to your problem, because two similar models with slightly different thresholds can have important differences in their balance specificity/sensitivity.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Erwan! While I am optimizing for specificity because I want to maximize the identification of true negatives, I am evaluating for multiple other metrics. Since specificity = TN/(TN+FP), I am aware of the pitfall of classifying everything as a negative will yield specificity = 1.0 (since all the TN will all be identified and there will be no FP). After reading your reply I have also optimized the same models for accuracy and the effect of random_state on train_test_split() still stands (added figure to main post as I don't seem to be able to do it in a comment).

Comment: Isn't the delta of accuracy a bit lower than in the previous graph? I don't remember, I might be wrong. Anyway if it's not this issue (or not only), then it would mean that the model is not stable (overfit). It might be the parameter tuning, this makes the model more accurate but also more specific to the training data.

Comment: @Erwan, that makes perfect sense, it must be overfitting the train set, over-estimating the performance in the grid search, not generalizing well and obviously underperforming in the test set. If I may pick your brain just once more: Do you think it would be appropriate/legitimate here to pick a set of hyperparameters, run the split in the separate 100 random states, compute average metrics and derive a confidence interval as representative metrics of the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think this makes sense. I think this would be similar to double cross-validation.